# Xcode 4.2 to Xcode 7.2 issues

Tags: xcode

I am migrating code I wrote fore Xcode4.2 into Xcode 7.2.
I get the following error:

```
ld: -pie can only be used when targeting iOS 4.2 or later
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Not sure what this is about... ?

Comment: I switched the targeting iOS and that solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deployment target is set to 4.0 but -pie can only be used when targeting iOS 4.2 or later as clearly stated by the above error message. Try setting your deployment target to 6.0. This is the lowest deployment target supported by Xcode 7.2.